# building cocos2d ios apps using eclipse

Tags: android, c++, ios, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I want to create apps for both android and IOS. I want to create IOS app using cocos2dx in eclipse and then convert it to android app(using NDK). how can I create ios app using cocos2d and eclipse in windows? I use cocos2dx v 3.4. I searched about it but I couldn't find any suitable tutorial for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code in eclipse all-right, but in order to build stuff for iOS you'd need to have an .xcodeproj with an appropriate target with all the source files set up for so that xcodebuild can build it.

I suppose it's possible to fiddle with xcode to force it to build via make and to munch up your makefile, but why do that?